# .NET Core 2.0 Minimal WebHost with Routes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, hosting

I'm trying to create an absolute minimal WebHost targeting netcoreapp2.0.
I've been refering to this without success: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?tabs=aspnetcore2x

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace netcore_pi_project
{
    class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args);

            using (var host = WebHost.Start(router => router
                .MapGet("volu", (req, res, data) => 
                    res.WriteAsync($"ps aux".Bash()))
                .MapGet("vold", (req, res, data) => 
                    res.WriteAsync($"ps aux".Bash()))))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Core Volume project running..");
                host.WaitForShutdown();
            }
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseUrls("http://localhost:5000")
                .Build();
    }
}
```

This builds but won't run:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: A valid non-empty application name must be provided.
>   Parameter name: applicationName
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostingEnvironmentExtensions.Initialize(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment, String applicationName, String contentRootPath, WebHostOptions options)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildCommonServices(AggregateException& hostingStartupErrors)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
>      at netcore_pi_project.Program.BuildWebHost(String[] args) in /Users/owe-macpro/projects/netcore-pi-project/Program.cs:line 31
>      at netcore_pi_project.Program.Main(String[] args) in /Users/owe-macpro/projects/netcore-pi-project/Program.cs:line 17

Comment: [Related issue on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/1137) (also the *very first result* on Google when searching for the error message)

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is on the [same page you linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?tabs=aspnetcore2x):

> ## Troubleshooting System.ArgumentException
>
> #### Applies to ASP.NET Core 2.0 Only
>
> If you build the host by injecting `IStartup` directly into the dependency injection container rather than calling `UseStartup` or `Configure`, you may encounter the following error: `Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: A valid non-empty application name must be provided.`
>
> This occurs because the `applicationName(ApplicationKey)` (the current assembly) is required to scan for `HostingStartupAttributes`. If you manually inject `IStartup` into the dependency injection container, add the following call to your `WebHostBuilder` with the assembly name specified:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseSetting("applicationName", "<Assembly Name>")
    ...
```

> Alternatively, add a dummy `Configure` to your `WebHostBuilder`, which sets the `applicationName(ApplicationKey)` automatically:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .Configure(_ => { })
    ...
```

> NOTE: This is only required with the ASP.NET Core 2.0 release and only when you don't call `UseStartup` or `Configure`.

Answer (score 0):

add the following in BuildWebHost:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
   // ... other Web Host configuration calls
   .UseSetting(WebHostDefaults.ApplicationKey, "[Application Name]")
```